# How to to re-use components between projects

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have two local projects - Project A and Project B.  Project A needs to utilize several components from project B.  How would I pull this off?  Would I somehow create an NPM package for project B and then include it in the webpack build for project A?  Or, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new project containing just the components you want to share (and all their dependencies).

1. If you want to open-source your components, [follow the `npm` docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages) for publishing your package. Then you (and anyone else) can use a simple `npm install <name>` to install and use your components.
2. If you don't want to open-source them and you have money to spend on it, [npm enterprise](https://www.npmjs.com/enterprise) will allow you to set up a private npm repository and use `npm install <name>` to install your components without sharing them.
3. If you don't want to go through all that hassle, but you do have your component pushed to a git service (github, bitbucket, or others), you can use `npm install <git remote url>` to install directly from the repository ([see docs here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)). This will allow you to install the package in multiple locations without involving npm.
4. If you are OK with just keeping the new project on your own development  machine, put it into another folder and install it via `npm install <folder>`.

In all cases you will need to have a `package.json` file in the new project. That's how npm determines the project name and version.